# How can I force okhttp to use http/2 for a request?

Tags: okhttp, http2

I'd like to make a request and force it to use the Protocol.HTTP_2.
I tried the code below:

```
import okhttp3.{OkHttpClient, Protocol, Request}

import scala.collection.JavaConversions._
import scala.collection.mutable.ListBuffer

object Main2 extends App {
  val url = "https://google.com/"
  val client = new OkHttpClient.Builder().protocols(ListBuffer(Protocol.HTTP_2)).build()
  val request = new Request.Builder().url(url).build()
  val response = client.newCall(request).execute()
  println(response.body().string())
}
```

But a got the error: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: protocols doesn't contain http/1.1: [h2]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

OkHttp will automatically use HTTP/2 if it’s available, but you can’t disable HTTP/1.1.

Comment: It doesn't seem to work if my server is multiplexing HTTP/1.1 and HTTP/2

Answer (score 5):

If you aren't using SSL/TLS you can use `Protocol.H2_PRIOR_KNOWLEDGE` instead of `Protocol.HTTP_2` when creating the OkHttpClient.

This will send a cleartext HTTP/2 that doesn't first negotiate with the service on which protocol to use.

For me, this forces HTTP/2 when the server is multiplexing HTTP/1.1 and HTTP/2.

Source: https://square.github.io/okhttp/3.x/okhttp/okhttp3/Protocol.html#H2_PRIOR_KNOWLEDGE